# <img> and <span> inside <a>, and only the span works as a link

Tags: html, css

I have a menu, with icons (`img`) and text underneath (`span`). I want both of them to be clickable as a link. I have this html for each item of the menu:

```
<div class="menu_item">
    <a href="menu/viewTemplates.html">
        <img class="menu_icon" src="images/icons/template.png" alt="Templates"/>
        <span>Templates</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

When I click on the `img`, nothing happens, but when I click on the `span`, the link works fine. This happens in both Chrome and Firefox. Everywhere I've read, people seem to have no problem doing this, except for IE, but this is not my case. Please, any ideas as to what could be making this not work?.

I tried it like this, and it works:

```
<div class="menu_item">
    <a href="menu/downloadTemplates.html">
        <div class="menu_icon" id="lnkDownloadTemplates"></div>
        <span>Download</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

But I still want to know why the other way, that is supposed to be the correct, Is not working for me.

**CSS:**

```
.menu_item{
    height: 15%;
    width: 45%;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu_icon{
    width:auto;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: [not working](https://jsfiddle.net/9fusum8p/)? thats weird, can inspect element the page? look for javascript events that bound to the image..

Comment: Works in Chrom & Firefox for me : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yoVJxx

Comment: @BagusTesa ¿How an I look for events bounded to a specific element?. I'm working on webStorm, and I searched all trough my project, and I see no other place, not in JS nor in HTML or CSS where that image is being summoned. Thank you for commenting :)

Comment: Icons are often better treated as background elements. See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zdoBbV for a quick and dirty example.

Comment: Also, check for any other transparent elements that may be overlaying the image using your browser developer tools. As we've demonstrated, the code you have provided works.

Comment: works for me in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/26g8y49c/ cna you make a working example with your problem? msot likely your adding some unwanted css to the img

Comment: @CarmenCamacho You want the text **undernearth** , but your CSS looks like you want the on single line. BTW, couldn't reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.menu_item {
  height: 15%;
  width: 45%;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu_item a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu_item a .menu_icon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu_item">
    <a href="menu/viewTemplates.html">
        <img class="menu_icon" src="http://cl.jroo.me/z3/q/R/R/d/a.aaa-Unique-Nature-Beautiful-smal.jpg" alt="Templates"/>
        <span>Templates</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Is this the same that you are looking for?

Hope this helps.

Comment: I found out it had nothing to do with css or html u__u, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using display: block; As anchor tag is by default inline.
Your HTML:-

```
 <div class="menu_item">
        <a href="https://www.google.com">
            <img class="menu_icon" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-uniblog-publish-prod/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png" alt="Templates"/>
            <span>Templates</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Your CSS-

```
 .menu_item a {
   display:block;
 }
 .menu_item{
    height: 15%;
    width: 45%;
    text-align: center;
   }
 .menu_icon{
    width:auto;
    height:100%;
  }
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't solve it for me :/. As some people already told me, I must have some JS  messing with this, but can't seem to find it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the problem was on a JS code that was taking the ID's of my elements (I didn't include the ID's when I posted my question) and overriding the linking.